# Important Question: ICO, How are the "Roadmaps" of "Contracts"

Tags: contract-development, ico, crowdsale

I would really like to know this if there's someone willing to support this quite easy, but great to know, before doing anything wrong about the road to ICO.

Question:

How's the road to do on the way to ICO? I'd know the main coding and making of it but, i just want to make this clear. Is it like this:

Deploy the ERC20 coin token, First

Deploy a Crowdsell contract for selling it.

Deploy a numerous of other contracts. For the crowdselling and other.

But what about the First, when deploying the ERC20 Token? Is that the one that should be audited and secured before you make all those after contracts? This question would really help many of us out.

Comment: Are you asking if your ERC20 should be audited?

Comment: Part of, The main question here says, the "road" towards ICO. Basically is the contract that you first deploy the Erc20 token, the most important ones that have to be audited? The other alternative question asks about the path to ICO way, basically, if it's Deploying erc20 tokens first, then crowdsell, preico- then crowdsale ICO.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions... You cannot deploy a crowdsale contract without a token. So the "Path" is deploy token, deploy crowdsale.

The first question is still confusing. It sounds like you want to get away from auditing your contracts. Each contract is just as important as the next. Most are immutable and cannot be changed once deployed. The token contract is just as important as the crowdsale contract. There's no weight on one or the other.